# template member function signature conflicts to non-template member function signature

Tags: c++, templates, vector, member, generic-programming

I recently had a question when implementing my own Vector container for study purpose.

In my Vector class a non-template member function and a template member function with the same name are declared (insert function). In case of conflict (when some template specialization matches the non-template function signature exactly), compiler gave me error....

Suppose that my vector class has 2 functions called insert:

```
/* Vec.h */
template <class T> class Vec {
public:
    iterator insert ( iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val );

    template <class InputIterator>
    iterator insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
}
#include "Vec.hpp"
```

In Vec.hpp:

```
/* Vec.hpp */
template <class T>
typename Vec<T>::iterator Vec<T>::insert( iterator position, 
                                          size_type n, 
                                          const value_type& val)
{
    /* Implementation */
}

template <class T> template <class InputIterator>
typename Vec<T>::iterator Vec<T>::insert( iterator position,
                                          InputIterator first,
                                          InputIterator last )
{
    /* Some code ... */

    /* Copy the element */
    while( first != last )
    {
        new ( position + idx ) T(*first);
        ++idx;
        ++first;
    }

    /* Some other code ... */
}
```

In main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Vec<int> myVec;
    MyVec.push_back(5);
    myVec.insert( myVec.begin(), 3, 3);
}
```

Compiler error:

```
../Vec.hpp: In instantiation of ‘T* Vec<T>::insert(Vec<T>::iterator, InputIterator, InputIterator) [with InputIterator = int; T = int; 
Vec<T>::iterator = int*]’:
../main.cpp:128:45:   required from here
../Vec.hpp:306:30: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) 
new ( position + idx ) T(*first);
                          ^
```

It seems like compiler tries to use the template insert function instead of non-template one. This is contradict with what I thought. And it looks like although I did not provide the argument list for insert function:

```
myVec.insert<int*>
```

The compiler implicitly instantiate the template insert function with int type.

In [member templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template) from cppreference, it also says that the compiler should use non-template one in this case.(Please refer to Member function templates section)

My environment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609

Please

1. explain why the compiler uses template member function
2. Provide solution to the above issue. so that when I do insert( iterator, int, int) or other similar function calls such as insert( iterator, unsigned int/long, unsigned int/long), it will call the proper member function.

Thanks everyone's help. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: In future, please post code all in one piece. No assembly required. Read: [MCVE] As it is, where are the `#include`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myVec.insert( myVec.begin(), 3, 3);
```

First thing that happens is that it finds all possible overloads:

```
iterator insert ( iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val );
template <class InputIterator>
iterator insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

then it does template argument deduction.  In this case, `InputIterator=int` is valid.

```
iterator insert ( iterator position, size_type n, const int& val );
template <>
iterator insert (iterator position, int first, int last);
```

as both `3` and `3`  are of type `int`.

Now it does ocerload resolution.  The template function here has zero conversions.  The non-template one requires converting `int` to `size_type`.

The one with zero conversions wins.  If they *tied*, then the non-template function wins on ties; but zero conversion wins.

Note that the iterator type is `int` not `int*`; this causes the body to fail to compile, because `int` cannot be dereferenced.